# Is it possible to create and run a thread in PHP?

Tags: php

When a PHP page is displayed then I want to start a thread searching for the last value entered in a MySQL table column so that the value of a text input field should be this last value incremented by 1 (it's a number). I want a thread because the page may be displayed for a long time and during that time the column may has been updated many times, so I want to get the value each period of a time interval. When clicking the submit button then the value should be last one in the column. Is that possible ?

---

Consider this scenario :

one user displays the page , so the field contains the incremented value. Then another user displays the same page, so the field contains also the same incremented value. When they submit the form then there is concurrency problem because they submit the same incremented data ! So how to resolve that situation ?

Comment: Why does it have to be a thread? Why not look it up straight away? Does it take that long to look up the value?

Comment: PHP is single threaded so you cannot do this.

Comment: @pheromix, Then shouldn't you look up the value when the user posts the form?

Comment: @laurent, you kind of can with multi curl and execs, but I think Ajax would also do here

Comment: Not is it only not possible, I don't even see this being applicable in any scenario. What's wrong with loading up the page, getting the value from MySQL and displaying it? So what if it takes a long time? It's either going to time out or get the latest value it found in the database.

Comment: Why do you need this in the first place? The usual way to do this is to determine the highest ID when the new record is posted, or to use an auto increment field. Is that not an option?

Comment: @pheromix - there isn't.

Comment: Look carefully at my comment. Why do you need this in the first place? Why not determine the highest value *at the time of saving*?

Comment: @pheromix - you have an issue with your design. I can come up with at least 2 other scenarios where you can run in the same problem. That's why you need to stop using that whatever increment value for posting forms and rely on a different method. Or, you can listen to other people and use ajax for no valid reason. You can't solve this with threads, most likely you can't solve it with transactions either. It might be better explaining **why** those numbers have to be the latest ones displayed to the users.

Comment: Wow, so you're GIVING a reference number to the USER so the USER can give it back? Why? Pekka already told you it's better to do that at the point of SAVING. You don't have to send numbers back and forth. Or you can simply use MySQL's `UUID()` or PHP's `uniqid()` to generate a unique string identifying something.

Comment: Would using an auto increment and displaying the number to the user *after* saving not be an alternative? Or as @N.B. says, create a unique ID that doesn't have the danger of collisions.

Comment: in fact the pattern of the reference data is a hierarchical number like 1.1.1 ; so I must increment only the last number so that it will be 1.1.2 ! So the problem is that if two users generate the same data 1.1.2 !!!

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but this is a terrible design. Not only from the way this "feature" works, but from the point of having an arbitrary database. Anyone who's worked with database **properly** knows that abstraction layers / you_name_it won't cut it, you either decide for a db or you are in world of problems. But let's assume that you manage to do what you want, you give your user a reference number, user sends it back. What if I'm advanced user and I change that number in the HTML itself? Or I'm the competition and I can see number of records by looking up that ref. number I get back?

Comment: So? I can change the field using javascript console or just modify the string that's going to be sent to your URL, it's really 0 difficulty to break it. Besides, take Chrome for example > right click an element, select inspect, change any piece of text you wish - submit your form and see if people can't change it at will :) and that's only with Chrome, other browsers can do it too using their dev. consoles. It's a flawed system, easily hackable, without any restriction whatsoever and it gives out the counter that's of business value. It's simply not good design.

Comment: yes but let's suppose the user doesn't do that ! even suppose the user doesn't know that !

Comment: User connects. PHP makes blank entry. Use MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the auto_increment generated. Send it back to the user. Once user submits the form back to you, use that number to populate the blank record whose primary key is the number sent via the form. Also, expect to have issues, this is such bad design and I'd fire people if I ever saw them even think about this. You're not only exposing your system to outside influences, you're endangering your potential clients this way. However, it's your thing so good luck with it.

Comment: @pheromix the thing is that even without malicious intent, this is a system designed to break. It takes only one user's request taking a few seconds longer than the other's and your numbering will go to hell

Answer (score 3):

> one user displays the page , so the field contains the incremented value. Then another user displays the same page, so the field contains also the same incremented value. When they submit the form then there is concurrency problem because they submit the same incremented data ! So how to resolve that situation ?

You will not be able to keep abreast of all the possible changes to the highest value in real time. An Ajax based solution which periodically fetches the value  will not be  fast and  reliable enough. What happens if the highest value changes in exactly those 100ms that my request takes to make it to the server? What if a user's network connection is temporarily down, he clicks "save", and two values end up overwriting each other?

The *usual* solution is to determine the highest value not in the user interface, but *at the time of storing the record in the database*. A way to achieve this effect automatically is using an auto increment field in the database.

If you absolutely *need* to display the current value to the user, you will need to employ some sort of locking mechanism. Ie. determine the currently highest value, and reserve that value for the current user until they either save the record, or leave the page. But there is simply no way to display the highest current value to every user in a 100% reliable way. You *will* end up with collisions this way. Like @N.B. says in the comments, you probably should rethink your design.

Comment: `The usual solution is to determine the highest value not in the user interface, but at the time of storing the record in the database.` : The generated data should be displayed within the field, and it should reflect changes in the database at any times while the page is displayed !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through AJAX easily by calling the database or a controller asynchronously every 1 minutes for example - or on a particular mouse event perhaps -  and returning JSON data or a view with displayed data. Many popular social network sites do this to get the latest feed / data displayed on their home page.

More info on: http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh